# SQL query taking too long to execute (SQL server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem in my application while executing a SQL query. I attached SQL Profiler to see the problem.

A query like

```
SELECT abc_id 
FROM abc_Master 
WHERE abc_name = @abcName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
  AND (status=''active'' OR status=''live'')
```

is taking 60.102 seconds to execute.

I have noticed an audit login log record above this query log in server profiler trace list.

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

Is this causing the delay? why is the query taking 60 secs to execute?

Comment: how many rows has abc_Master?

Comment: The audit login event just indicates a new connection (or it also shows existing connections by default). It won't be related. The explicit `COLLATE` clause likely means an index on `abc_name` won't be used. What does the execution plan look like? Why don't you define the column to be of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` collation if that is what you need?

Comment: (1) do you have an index on (`abc_name, status`) ?? (2) Why are you specifying a specific collation - this could cause massive performance hits when SQL Server needs to convert strings from one collation to another.....

Comment: abc_Master has only 23 records

Comment: @Rajneesh - In that case you are probably being blocked by an open transaction.

Comment: there are no indexes on (abc_name, status). do we need them even if the  abc_Master  is expected to have <50 records?

Comment: A table scan on a table with 20 records shouldn't take 60s, so indexes are probably not your bottle neck. Does this query consistently take around 60 seconds, or does it *occasionally* take that long to execute?

Comment: Noting the double single-quotes around your statuses; are we to assume that this is a part of a dynamic query? Is there more to this query, that we're not seeing?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, there is an open transaction as @Martin Smith has told.